# Referencing Silverlight UI Automation Helper dll in CodedUI Test

Tags: c#, silverlight, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to automate a Silverlight web application using CodedUI. The application under test is already developed and deployed in our testing environment.

I tried automating using record feature of CodedUI but was unsuccessful in getting the recorded actions. On googling, I found that I have to install this plugin: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28312a61-9451-451a-990c-c9929b751eb4

I did the installation and still was unable to record. Then I found that I have to reference Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.SilverlightUIAutomationHelper.dll file in the Silverlight project.

This is where I am stuck. I am not sure whether to reference this file in :

1. The project which was used to develop the Silverlight application
2. The CodedUI test project.

If it is option 1, I don't have access to the development project. Is there any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you only have to reference it in the Coded UI test project. This is how I do it with the DevExpress.CodedUIExtension helper DLL.

Personally I would put the test code next to the application code though, when you version the tests with the application this will make it possible to run tests against a previous and or branched version.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. But this link here suggests us to add the SilverlightUIAutomationHelper.dll to the Silevrlight development project not the test project. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg313838%28v=vs.100%29.aspx. Am I wrong in this ?

Comment: I think you are right. Best way is to try 2 and if it does not work, ask the development team for a test version which includes the Helper.dll. It would help if the dev-team assists in making the application testable. If that is for some reason impossible you could have a look at image based testing tools like: http://www.sikuli.org/

Comment: I have already tried sikuli... But found the issues with image based automation like resolution, OCR support limitation making it not an ideal tool.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,You need to Refer the AutomationHelper.dll in The project which was used to develop the Silverlight application. I was having same issue way back refering to dll will solve the purpose.

In addition you can refer it with flag to make sure this will not go to production which is a best practice.